# Upgrading pip version to master branch in github before tox install dependencies

Tags: python, pip, tox

I want to upgrade my pip version to `pip 10.0.0.dev0` with master pip version in github like `pip install -I https://github.com/pypa/pip/archive/master.zip#egg=pip`before tox installs the dependencies. Is there a way to this?

My current tox file is like below

```
[tox]
envlist = py36

[testenv]
passenv = *
deps=
  -rrequirements.txt
commands=
  pip --version
  pytest tests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to upgrade `pip` before installing dependencies is to
stop using `deps` and run everything in `commands`:

```
[testenv]
commands=
  pip install -I https://github.com/pypa/pip/archive/master.zip#egg=pip
  pip install -rrequirements.txt
  pytest tests
```